# Why doesn't the name function work. The chrome console outputs 'string is not a function'?

Tags: javascript, html

Why doesn't the name function work. The chrome console outputs 'string is not a function'? Please provide the answer. Thanks

```
 <html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function name(){
    alert('hello, world');
    }

    // with parameters
    function test(x){
    alert(x);
    }
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form>
 <input type="button" value="Press Me" name="foo" onClick="name()" />
</form>
 <a href="#" onClick="test('help')">help</a>
 <a href="#" onClick="name()">name</a>
 <script>
 name();
</script></code>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

`window.name` is already a property that exists. When you have global functions, they also get put on the global object, but `name` gets converted to a string. It’s as if you were doing this:

```
window.name = function name() {
    …
};
```

You can…

- Pick a different name for the function
- Make the function anonymous and bind it through JavaScript (looks good)
- Put all your functions in a function wrapper and bind it through JavaScript (looks better)

Here’s an example of that last one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Some page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="button" value="Press Me" id="foo">
        </form>

        <a href="#" id="help">help</a>
        <a href="#" id="name">name</a>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            function name() {
                alert('hello, world');
            }

            // with parameters
            function test(x) {
                alert(x);
            }

            document.getElementById("foo").onclick = name;
            document.getElementById("name").onclick = name;
            document.getElementById("help").onclick = function() {
                test('help');
            };
        })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `window.name` not settable then?

Comment: @Eric `window.name` is settable, but in most browsers it can only be a string. But in this case I think dystroy's answer is correct, although I have no idea where this strange behavior is specified.

Answer (score 3):

In your input, the name is "foo" as you could see by running this :

```
<input type="button" value="Press Me" name="foo" onClick="alert(name)" />
```

(it alerts "foo")

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ALOQedeQ/1/)

Simply give another name to your function.

Or better, take immediately the good habit to not inline javascript :

```
<input type="button" id=foo value="Press Me" name="foo"/>
...
<script>
   document.getElementById('foo').onclick=name;
</script>
```

Comment: +1, but what the heck... how does this work? I can see `this.name` returning `"foo"`, but how does `name` exist in the scope of this function (and not from `window.name`)? Is this behavior described in some part of some spec?

Comment: Well... You might find [the properties of input here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) or notice you've set it yourself but you usually mostly find them when you get bitten. The solution is to follow the best practice : don't inline javascript in your HTML elements.

Comment: But this doesn't explain how the tag's attributes become upvalues of inlined functions?

Comment: The event handler is executed in a scope descendant from the input, whose attributes are also properties.

Comment: Yes, I get that, but that just means you can do `this.name`, right? How does `name` become part of a VO in the scope of the function?

Comment: Thank you. It works fine now that the I changed the function name